# Pandas missing rows when importing using delimiter ="|"

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with 51,347 rows. When import the data using pandas and set the delimiter to "|" , I lose 394 rows.

```
 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.read_csv("Basin11.txt", sep='|', error_bad_lines=False, 
 dtype={'Start Date': str, 'Greater Than/Less Than': str, 
'Parameter Code': float, 'Start Time': str, 'Start Depth': float, 'Composite Category': str,
'Composite Type': str})
 print(len(df.index))
```

If I remove the sep variable, the data won't load as multiple columns but will load the proper number of rows. It only seems to be an issue for this file. 
[Basin11.txt File](http://newcoastalatlas.tamug.edu/download/Basin/basin11.txt)

Does anyone know why I'm losing data?

Comment: I would imagine around 394 rows have their column with "free" text containing an unescaped | , and error_bad_lines=False ignore silently those rows

Comment: I've tried removing the error_bad_lines=False, but it has no effect on the length. We removed each of the arguments individually with no effect except sep='|'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started going through your input file and found a number of errors that may be leading to the "missing rows".

The comments line 3491 and 9805 have an opening `"` but is missing the closing `"`.  This would cause matching issues, including the following rows as part of the comment body.  As I started fixing those, the line counts started going up.  There are probably more cases of this.

Also, some lines have double-double quotes (`""`) for opening and closing comments.  For example:

> ""green, med tide, 10-15 mph winds""

Edit:  I added the following code:

```
for comment in df['Comments'].values:
    print(comment)
```

Then ran `python3 sample.py | grep '|' | wc -l`, to find the number of comments that contained `|`, and got 394 (The number of rows that you are missing)

Comment: Thank you that fixed it! I then needed to add the argument quoting =3 to the read_csv file.